# function in queen's Attack II returns wrong answer

Tags: c, algorithm

I'm solving [Queen's Attack II problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/queens-attack-2/problem) in Hackerrank. My idea is traverse through every obstacles to find the closest obstacle in each directions (left, right, up down and 4 diagons. My function only passed half of testcases. Then I search on the Internet and I found a similar solution but different in code structure, obsiously it passed all testcases.

My function:

```js
int queensAttack(int n, int k, int r_q, int c_q, int obstacles_rows, int obstacles_columns, int **obstacles) {
    long a[8];
    a[0]=c_q-1;
    a[1]=n-c_q;
    a[2]=r_q-1;
    a[3]=n-r_q;
    a[4]=min(a[3], a[1]);
    a[5]=min(a[2], a[1]);
    a[6]=min(a[2], a[0]);
    a[7]=min(a[3], a[0]);

    int x=obstacles[i][1], y=obstacles[i][0];
 
    for (int i=0; i<obstacles_rows; i++) {
        if(y==r_q && x<c_q) a[0]=min(a[0], c_q-x-1);

        else if(y==r_q && x>c_q) a[1]=min(a[1], x-c_q-1);

        else if(x==c_q && y<r_q) a[2]=min(a[2], r_q-y-1);
    
        else if(x==c_q && y>r_q) a[3]=min(a[3], y-r_q-1);
    
        else if(y-r_q==x-c_q) a[4]=min(a[4], y-r_q-1);
    
        else if(r_q-y==x-c_q) a[5]=min(a[5], r_q-y-1);
    
        else if(r_q-y==c_q-x) a[6]=min(a[6], r_q-y-1);
    
    else if(y-r_q==c_q-x) a[7]=min(a[7], y-r_q-1);
    }
    
    int result=0;
    for (int i=0; i<8; i++) {
        result+=a[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Their fucntion:

```js
int queensAttack(int n, int k, int r_q, int c_q, int obstacles_rows, int obstacles_columns, int **obstacles) {
a[0] = c_q -1 ;
    a[1] = n -r_q;
    a[2] = n -c_q;
    a[3] = r_q -1;
    a[4] = min(a[0],a[1]);
    a[5] = min(a[1],a[2]);
    a[6] = min(a[2],a[3]);
    a[7] = min(a[3],a[0]);

    int x,y;

    while (--k >= 0)
    {
        y = obstacles[k][0] - r_q;
        x = obstacles[k][1] - c_q;
        if (x == 0)
        {
            if (y > 0)
            {
                a[1] = min(a[1], y - 1);
            }
            else
            {
                a[3] = min(a[3], -(y + 1));
            }
        }
        else if (y == 0)
        {
            if (x > 0)
            {
                a[2] = min(a[2], x - 1);
            }
            else
            {
                a[0] = min(a[0], -(x + 1));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            float m = (float)y / x;
            if (m == 1.0)
            {
                if (x > 0)
                {
                    a[5] = min(a[5], x - 1);
                }
                else
                {
                    a[7] = min(a[7], -y - 1);
                }
            }
            else if (m == -1.0)
            {
                if (x > 0)
                {
                    a[6] = min(a[6], x - 1);
                }
                else
                {
                    a[4] = min(a[4], y - 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    int result=0;
    for (int i=0; i<8; i++) {
        result+=a[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Where am I wrong?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I only use `a[]` in `queensAttack` function and return the sum of it. Why `a[]` has to be seen global?

Comment: You reference `i` before it is defined? That line, that defines `x` and `y` should be within the loop body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some issues:

1) This line should not occur *before* the loop, but as a first statement *inside* the loop body:

```
    int x=obstacles[i][1], y=obstacles[i][0];
```

2) The second half of the loop has conditions which cause a problem. For instance when `y-r_q==x-c_q` is true, then also `r_q-y==c_q-x` is true, and vice versa. So this expression tells you whether an obstacle is on a queen's diagonal, but not on which *side* of the queen. As a consequence, the argument you pass to the `min` function could be negative, and this should never happen. You need an additional condition, much like you have in the first half of that `if`-chain. So change the second half to this:

```
    else if(y-r_q==x-c_q && y>r_q) a[4]=min(a[4], y-r_q-1);   
    else if(r_q-y==x-c_q && y<r_q) a[5]=min(a[5], r_q-y-1);
    else if(r_q-y==c_q-x && y<r_q) a[6]=min(a[6], r_q-y-1);    
    else if(y-r_q==c_q-x && y>r_q) a[7]=min(a[7], y-r_q-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

It took me some time to figure out this one. My first code couldn't get through the time execution time limits. So, some math comes handy. First I calculate the total number of moves as there are no obstacles, just using math. If there are no obstacles that is the answer.

If there are obstacles, loop through them, using boolean to close each direction that is found and using math calculate the non moves. But I still had error, because the obstacles had to be sorted from the queen to the farthest obstacles position.

Here is my code in Java.

```
int vertHor = n - 1;
    int d1 = Math.min(n - c_q, n - r_q) + Math.min(r_q - 1, c_q - 1);
    int d2 = Math.min(c_q - 1, n - r_q) + Math.min(n - c_q, r_q - 1);
    int total = vertHor * 2 + d1 + d2;
    if (k == 0) {
        return total;
    }
    boolean u = false;
    boolean d = false;
    boolean l = false;
    boolean r = false;
    boolean ul = false;
    boolean ur = false;
    boolean dl = false;
    boolean dr = false;
    
    Arrays.sort(obstacles, (int[] x, int[] y) -> Math.min(Math.abs(x[0] - r_q), Math.abs(x[1] - c_q))
            - Math.min(Math.abs(y[0] - r_q), Math.abs(y[1] - c_q)));

    for (int[] obs : obstacles) {
        int oRow = obs[0];
        int oCol = obs[1];
        if (oRow == r_q) {
            if (oCol < c_q && !l) {
                total -= oCol;
                l = true;
            } else if (!r) {
                total -= n - oCol + 1;
                r = true;
            }
        } else if (oCol == c_q) {
            if (oRow < r_q && !d) {
                total -= oRow;
                d = true;
            } else if (!u) {
                total -= n - oRow + 1;
                u = true;
            }
        } else if (Math.abs(c_q - oCol) == Math.abs(r_q - oRow)) {//oCol != c_q && oRow != r_q) {
            if (oCol < c_q && oRow > r_q && !ul) {
                total -= Math.min(n - oRow + 1, oCol);
                ul = true;
            } else if (oCol < c_q && oRow < r_q && !dl) {
                total -= Math.min(oRow, oCol);
                dl = true;
            } else if (oCol > c_q && oRow < r_q && !dr) {
                total -= Math.min(oRow, n - oCol + 1);
                dr = true;
            } else if (oCol > c_q && oRow > r_q && !ur) {
                total -= Math.min(n - oRow, n - oCol) + 1;
                ur = true;
            }
        }
        if (u && d && l && r && ul && ur && dl && dr) {
            break;
        }
    }

    return total;
```